# Alter value of hash if key exists in hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to alter the value of a hash if the key exists in the hash. I have my algorithm working to alter it to the correct value the only issue is that it alters all values in the hash rather than just the one I want. How do I only alter certain values in a hash?

I have tried the hash.has_key?(key) method and it still alters all my values

```
if @hash.has_key?(k)
  @hash.select {|k,v| v.price = (v.price/100)}
else 
  print "Key not found"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

`has_key?` is not your problem... `Hash#select` iterates over all the values.

Here's two options:

```
@hash.select{|k,v| v.price /= 100 if k == key}
```

or

```
if @hash.has_key?(key)
  @hash[key].price /= 100
else 
  print "Key not found"
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicated answer. Mine was even a little bit wrong.

Comment: Thank you v much :) the first option works but not the 2nd for some reason